# Recursing nested objects

Tags: php, recursion

I have an object containing nested objects and so on. The level of nesting can be assumed to be infinite.

If the object nests other objects, then the children should be stored in an array property called `childElements`.

The object I am working with looks like this:

```
Object
   childElements
       ['object1'] => object
                         childElements
                            ['object11'] => object

       ['object2'] => object
```

I would like to get a reference to the object called `object11` using recursion. This is the function I am using. The function resides in a class, so `$this` is used when calling the recursion:

```
public function recursiveSearch(array $childElements, $elementName){
    foreach ($childElements as $key => $element) {
        var_dump($key);
        if (isset($element->childElements)){

            return $this->recursiveSearch($element->childElements, $elementName);

        }else{
            if ($key == $elementName){
                return $childElements[$elementName];
            }
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("$elementName could not be found.");
}
```

I then call my function like so (assuming that object is called `$r`):

```
return $this->recursiveSearch($r->childElements, 'object11');
```

The problem with my code (when looking at the var dumps is that the function will keep travelling towards the inner most object. But once that is done, it terminates, regardless of whether it has visited any other `childElements`. I believe the issue is due to `return $this->recursiveSearch` which forces a return prematurely.

How can I structure my recursive function so that it works properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code assumes that if an element has child elements, the element must be in the child elements. You actually need three conditions though:

- if the element itself is the searched-for element, return it
- if the element has children *and the searched-for element is in those children*, return it
- if none of the above *for all elements*, return `false` (don't throw an exception, because not finding the element is to be expected on most children)

Code:

```
public function recursiveSearch(array $childElements, $elementName){
    foreach ($childElements as $key => $element) {
        if ($key == $elementName) {
            return $element;
        }
        if (
            !empty($element->childElements) &&
            $element = $this->recursiveSearch($element->childElements, $elementName)
        ) {
            return $element;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe your logic problem is in your if-else statement. You are first checking to see if $childElements exists, and if so, you run recursiveSearch. You need to test for the key match first, and then check for children. That way if you found it, you don't start another recursion.

tldr; do if (key == name) { return element }  else { recursionSearch }.